# Excel Chart, Axis Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a problem with my Y Axis.

Here is a sample (click on it for a larger view):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OQfi1XM.png]

As you can see the  axis #'s are off. The chart numbers are actual finish times for stages in a race, these times occur anywhere from from 8 PM on T, till around 10 am on T+ 1. Having trouble showing this on the axis.

If anyone can help 1) Help adjust the axis settings to make this legible 2) Help format my dashed lines (Expected time), ex: a dashed line at 8 am (used for comparison with actual finish times)

If you need the workbook, please start a discussion with me or request a dropbox link.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Just to make sure I understand what's going on here -- you want the chart to show just the time, not the date and time? Is the unwanted date data in your Max Time values what's causing your chart to slope upwards?

Comment: Hi @Excellll , I have update the question to give a more detals